# NHibernate warning Narrowing proxy to - this operation breaks ==

Tags: c#, logging, nhibernate, proxy, warnings

I have a question about about proxy in NHibernate. I've inside in my log file a lot of logs like: Narrowing proxy to - this operation breaks ==
There are a few other questions on the web and different answer:

> [Stackoverflow NHibernate narrowing proxy warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267915/nhibernate-narrowing-proxy-warning) **It being a big deal or not depends on the level of risk you are willing to accept.** Since there is going to always been a disconnect between your code and your database you can not always assure that the casting will work. **This will lead to bugs that might be difficult to diagnose and may not be resolved without changes to the database or the code.**

Another post from hibernate:

> [Narrowing problem](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2404391) **Don't worry about his warning**, just put the following in your log file and you shouldn't see it anymore...
>
> Why it happens? 
>   Suppose you have a Product with a many-to-one association to Address. Both are entities and Address has a ShippingAddress subclass.
>
> Let's Session.get(..) a Product from the db that has ShippingAddress as association. Because the many-to-one is lazy, it will return a Address proxy. Note that this is a Address proxy and not a ShippingAddress proxy as the proxy will always match the type that is mentioned in Product (see the hibernate book for details).
>
> This proxy is stored by Hibernate in his proxy cache. 
>   Now we Session.get(...) the same ShippingAddress from the db, the one that is associated to the Product that we used fetched from the db. 
>   Now Hibernate will see that it already contains a proxy for this ShippingAddress and will return this. However, it will notice that the types aren't the same so a "downcasting" must occur. Because this latter action isn't possible with "proxies" it will create new one and return it...
>
> **As you can see, nothing to worry about.** 
>   You could consider making the Address a value type... 
>   In my case that's no option.

And a last one

> [ProxyWarnLog Removed in Hibernate 4?](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1030440)

Here is the code from NHibernate: [StatefulPersistenceContext.cs -> NarrowProxy(..)](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Engine/StatefulPersistenceContext.cs)

So, is it a problem or not? I always work with detached objects in my program.
I hope someone can help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a trouble if you use the `==` operator to compare entities and decide whether they are the same one or not.

This does similarly occur (but with `Equals` indeed) when you add an entity to a collection mapped as a `set`. If the set happens to already contain the entity but instantiated through another proxy type, the `add` *may* fail to respect its contract, it may add again the entity, and the `set` would then contains two occurrences of the same entity.

This is a *may*, not a *will*, because you can avoid this trouble by overriding `Equals` (and `GetHashcode`, as it is mandatory to return the same hashcode for objects being equal) on your entities, in order to compare them through their primary key and entity type. For `set`, it is sufficient (since it do not use the `==` operator, but the `Equals` method, prioritizing the one from `IEquatable<T>` if your type implements it).

For `==`, you need then to define the `==` and `!=` operators on your class for using your `Equals` implementation.

Read [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode) or [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/patternsandpractices/identity-field-equality-and-hash-code.html) for more on this. Beware, their example implementations are just examples, and are not suitable for a domain model using inheritance. Read [here](/q/5686604/1178314) for a overriding example handling inheritance. (But it does not handle transient entities: better append to it a final test on [natural ids](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-naturalid) if they have one, rather than yielding false if both are considered transient while being not the same reference.) And this [blog](https://ayende.com/blog/2500/generic-entity-equality) provides a base class with `==` redefined (found in this [Stack Overflow question](/q/11262747/1178314)).

Working with detached entities increases this risk. If you have not already overridden those two methods on your entities, it would be safer to do it, regardless of this warning.