# OfType<> not playing nicely with NHibernate Proxy class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have classes similar to the following:

```
public abstract class Base { }
public class Concrete : Base { }
public class Cement : Base { }
```

and the following code

```
var bases = someEntity.Bases; // returns two Concrete and once Cement

// bases now contains:
// - ProxyBase : Base
// - Concrete : Base
// - Cement : Base

var concretes = bases.OfType<Concrete>(); 

// concretes only contains one Concrete (i.e. the ProxyBase is ignored)
```

How can I get the desired result of two `Concrete`s without polluting my class with knowledge of NHibernate?

I also don't want to force the mapping to not use lazy loading if possible.

Comment: If `OfType` is not returning the value, I doubt the proxy is actually a subclass of `Concrete`.  What is the value of `proxy.GetType().BaseType.FullName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a pain point with dynamic proxies. You can add a Self property to the base class so that you can get a reference to the unproxied object:

```
public virtual Base Self
{
    get { return this; }
}
```

Then you can get the concrete classes of a certain type by examining the type:

```
var concretes = bases.Where(b => b.Self is Concrete);
```

You can also create an extension method so that OfType behaves as expected:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>(this IEnumerable<Base> bases) where T : Base
{
    return Enumerable.OfType<T>(bases.Select(b => b.Self));
}
```

Comment: It seems a shame to pollute my entities but this definitely is the simplest way - especially as it doesn't involve NH at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unproxy it first to get the concrete type.

```
public static T Unproxy<T>(this T obj, ISession session)
{
    if (!NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(obj))
    {
        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(obj);
    }

    if (obj is INHibernateProxy)
    {    
        return (T) session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.Unproxy(obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

then

```
foreach(var base in bases)
      Unproxy<Concrete>(base);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. This means that my method would require knowledge of NHibernate which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Then create a class that would wrap `NHibernate` so it doesn't know `NHibernate`.

Answer (score 0):

So I've come to a temporary solution - but this is fragile (if `ToString` gets overridden then it will break, other ORMs may work in a different way) and by no means satisfactory

```
var concreteTypeName = typeof(Concrete);

// yuck
var concretes = bases.Where(x => String.Equals(x.ToString(), concreteTypeName));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `INHibernateProxy` try this:

```
var concretes = bases.Where(x => {
        var proxy = (INHibernateProxy)x;
        return proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer.PersistentClass == typeof(Concrete);
    });
```

Or as [Kirk Woll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189950/kirk-woll) said:

```
var concretes = bases.Where(x => x.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Concrete));
```

Answer (score 0):

Proxy is a pain when it comes to test correct type.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755903/2555889) cover all of the differents solutions.

1. One solution is to use a `no-proxy` lazy loading, which should do the trick !  ([explanations](http://ayende.com/blog/4378/nhibernate-new-feature-no-proxy-associations))
2. The [Jamie Ide answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23162291/2555889) is to my mind the best solution if you cannot use `no-proxy` (for any reasons)

Good luck !